# how to view the diffrent languages in TextView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an application which contains paragraphs in 5 languages in 5 different XML pages, how can we do it? Do I need to use some library? The languages are:

1. Kannada
2. Telugu
3. Tamil
4. Hindi

Answer (score 2):

Because Android has been built with [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) in mind, there is no need for a library. Simply use different `strings.xml` in different folders.

For example:

- `res/values/strings.xml` for the default values
- `res/values-de/strings.xml` for the german translations

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_language) the countrycode for Tamil is `ta`:

```
res/values-ta/strings.xml
```

Comment: here am getting an error i.e "error:Found text string language = "hi";"

Comment: I need more information in order to help you.

Comment: in res/values-hi/strings.xml,     String language = "hi"; this line am getting that error

Comment: i have another idea, we can store in database by using utf-8 ci, and retrive it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need something like this
(Not sure about these four languages just giving my assumption, But the code works for English, Arabic, French)

**Create 5 values folder in your res**

1. values-kn //Kannada
2. values-te //Telugu
3. values-ta //Tamil
4. values-hi //Hindi
5. values-en //English

and add `strings.xml` for the respective language in every folder

And use the following code to change the language

```
String language = "";
language = "kn"; //For Kannada
language = "te"; //For Telugu
language = "ta"; //For Tamil
language = "hi"; //For Hindi
language = "en"; //For English

Locale locale = new Locale(language);
Resources res = getResources(); 
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
conf.locale = locale; 
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```